# Java, SSLSocket, receiving no answer

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, imap

I'm trying to use SSL with IMAP in java. I do not want to use the IMAP class.
For some reason, when I send the n th message, I receive the answer to message n-2, and not to message n-1. Which means that I don't receive any answer to the first message sent until I send the second message. Can anyone spot what's wrong in the following minimal code ? (It is indeed minimal, apart from the println, which, I guess, help debugging)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
public class Mail{
    static String server = "imap.gmail.com";
    static String user   = "straightouttascript@gmail.com";
    static String pass   = "azerty75";
    public static void print (PrintWriter to, String text){
        System.out.println("sent : "+text);
        to.println(text+ "\r");
        to.flush();
    }

    public static void read  (BufferedReader from) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        do {
            String line = from.readLine();
            System.out.println("received: "+line);
        } while (from.ready());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(server, 993);
            System.out.println("Start connexion");

            BufferedReader from = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslsocket.getInputStream()));
            //             read(from);

            PrintWriter to = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sslsocket.getOutputStream())), true);
            print(to,"a1 login "+user+" "+pass);
            read(from);/*exepcted:
                         OK gimap ready 
                         a1 OK login@host authenticated (Success)*/

            sslsocket.close();
            System.out.println("End connexion");
        }

        catch (Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using JavaMail for this?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending CRLF pairs? Rather than just line feeds?

Comment: @EJP One on my goal is also to undesrtand socket, and in particular secure socket

Comment: @MAX. Edited to add that, even if + "\r" is added at the end of the function to, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: So why not choose something simpler? I suggest you start with a simple echo server and client. IMAP is running before you can walk.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP is not a pingpong protocol. The server doesn't send one line in response to one of yours.

Rather, you send commands and the server sends information. The server is permitted to send you more information than you asked for, so you can get seven responses to one command, and you can even get a response without sending a command at all, which is then called an unsolicited response. Strange phrase. Unsolicited responses are used by some servers to notify you about new mail, by more to notify you about flag changes on messages, and by (almost?) all to notify you that they're about to close your connection.

Comment: I know all of this. My trouble is not that I receive more, is that I receive not enough. That is, sometime I just don't get any answer to my command before sending a new command to the server, Othertime (with bigger examples), I receive the first part of a response, and then nothing, while the  response is not ended.

Comment: IMAP really is not a pingpong protocol. Try starting another Thread and calling read() there, you'll see what I mean: The server sends you responses when it has something to say to you, without checking whether you or it has the pingpong ball. Just make a thread and read responses all the time in that read.